# arr.pop() popping out elements from other arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I apologize in advance to create such a trivial question but there is something I seriously don't grasp. I did look for explanation for this problem , but its quite hard to find it if you don't quite understand whats going on :).

```
function sampleCode(){
var sampleArr = [{"ID":"1","date":"2015-11-24","Name":"Alan"},{"ID":"2","date":"2015-11-26","Name":"Bob"}],
    returnArr = [],
    innerArr = [],
    simpleObj ={};
        simpleObj = {
            ID: sampleArr[0].ID,
            Name: sampleArr[0].Name
        }
        innerArr.push(simpleObj);
        returnArr.push(innerArr);
        innerArr.pop();}
```

I was going with this code through debugger on firefox and was wandering why after I pop the innerArr , why is the object being poped from returnArr ? Wouldn't the content inside returnArr be considered separate to innerArr.pop()?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your question but, when you push the innerArr into returnArr, you are storing a reference to the same actual array. So, if you pop from innerArr, all references to it will be affected.

Comment: That is what I was thinking , I guess I always assumed that pushing and poping pushes and pops the actual element and not the reference to it. We learn something new everyday i guess :) but then , could you tell me what would be the pest practice if I want to move the object from innerArr to returnArr without creating a new array. I guess the easiest way would be to pass innerArr to diffrent array and then push that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing, anything relevant starts from defining **simpleObj** as an Object

`{ID: "1", Name: "Alan"}`

- **simpleObj** becomes first item of **innerArr**
- **innerArr** becomes first item of **returnArr**
- You pop the first item from **innerArr** which is the first item of first item of **returnArr**

first or last.. there is only one element in each of these arrays.

Answer (score 3):

object being poped from returnArr because you are storing the instance of innerArr in returnArr .

You can use this code

```
function sampleCode(){
    var sampleArr = [{"ID":"1","date":"2015-11-24","Name":"Alan"},{"ID":"2","date":"2015-11-26","Name":"Bob"}],
    returnArr = [],
    var innerArr = [],
    simpleObj ={};
    simpleObj = {
        ID: sampleArr[0].ID,
        Name: sampleArr[0].Name
    }
    innerArr.push(simpleObj);
    returnArr.push(innerArr);
     // innerArr.pop();
}
```